# Error using and inserting GaugeChart in React Native

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I am new to React Native and currently creating an app in react native. I want to visualise a gauge chart, really liking this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gauge-chart. But I keep getting the same errors which I will explain and I have no idea how to fix them, and there is no answer on stackoverflow

I have made sure to install the package as so "npm install react-gauge-chart", and made sure the import is coming from the location in which the package is stored - pointing to "export default function GaugeChart(props: GaugeChartProps): React.ReactElement;" which is stored in a index.d.ts file within the react-gauge-chart folder within the @types folder within the node_modules.

I then imported it into the screen in which I wanted it to be in as such, "import GaugeChart from "react-gauge-chart";" and then have had multiple attempts at putting the GaugeChart in the return section using the following, `GaugeChart/`, < GaugeChart id="something" / > and even copying an example just to show a chart or any chart.

I have wrapped the `GaugeChart` in everything from `View` to `div` to < > and nothing simply inserting it between the two text tags I already had on the page.

But, I keep getting this error when I run:
"Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter."
Just below it shows where and it says:

This error is located at:
in div (created by GaugeChart)

I searched StackOverflow and found an answer, simply changing the:
"import GaugeChart from "react-gauge-chart";" to
"import {GaugeChart} from "react-gauge-chart";".

I did this, but then I was hit with another error:

"Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

And when I searched stackoverflow, it said the fix for this happens to be the change I made changing the:
"import {GaugeChart} from "react-gauge-chart";" to
"import GaugeChart from "react-gauge-chart";".

I, then attempted to move on and download a separate package such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-speedometer, following it exactly as it is laid out but I ended up getting the exact same error.

I have no idea how to fix this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

React UI libraries are built on web components and won't work in React Native.    What would be a div in React is a View in React Native.  You can either

- find a similar library built for React Native (this is one a quick search turned up, but it doesn't seem to have the niceties of the ones you listed: https://github.com/LucasMonteiro1/react-native-speedometer-chart)
- make your own component based on how the React library is built